# How to resolve a while loop and if statment issue in as little code as posisble

Tags: python, loops

I am attempting to allow my list to check if a user says no to the request, 
if so for it to activate my if block allowing me to invite another guest in their place. 
Each time I type no, rather than activating the if block it continunes to print, where am I going wrong? or What elements am I missing?

```
guestllist = ["me","batman","joker","wonder woman","peter rabbit"]
normal = guestllist
guestllist.reverse()

while len(normal):
    # print("welome to the party "  + guestllist.pop())
    result = input("can you come " + guestllist.pop() + "?")
    if result == "no":
        print(result + " cannot make it")
        input("our new guest shall be ")
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation?

Comment: remove `while len(normal):` and write `for _ in range(len(guestllist)):`

Comment: _Please_ fix your indentation. Correct indentation is _vital_ in Python.

Comment: What do you expect `input("our new guest shall be ")` to do? BTW, doing `normal = guestllist` doesn't create a new list. You have a single list object which now has 2 names, `guestllist` and `normal`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
guestllist = ["me","batman","joker","wonder woman","peter rabbit"]
guestllist.reverse()
while len(guestllist):
    result = input("can you come " + guestllist.pop() + "?")
    if result == "no":
        print(result + " cannot make it")
        input("our new guest shall be ")
```

Comment: Thanks this really helps